# I would like regex to pick all the lines into the <message> group until the next line that starts with the time

Tags: regex

I have been using regex101 to trouble shoot this statement:

This does stop at 2 digits, but drops the next line where the \d{2} starts:

```
/(?P<time>^(\d{2}(:|.))+)\s?(?P<Token>\[T\:\d+\])?\s?(?P<event_type>\{\w+\:\d+\})?\s(?P<message>(.*)(?=\d{2}))/gm
```

This gets to the end of the line but never to the next lines without starting with the time:

```
(?P<time>^(\d{2}(:|.))+)\s?(?P<Token>\[T\:\d+\])?\s?(?P<event_type>\{\w+\:\d+\})?\s(?P<message>((.*\n))(?=\d{2}\:))
```

This gets me to the end of the line but wont pick up the next lines not starting with the time:

```
/(?P<time>^(\d{2}(:|.))+)\s?(?P<Token>\[T\:\d+\])?\s?(?P<event_type>\{\w+\:\d+\})?\s(?P<message>.*)/gm
```

I put the expected part in BOLD to be in the group 'message'

```
15:36:32.448 [T:1401135292433] {ScxmlMetric:3} **METRIC <log sid='~28~01TF8DKFD49SREES00000J' expr='~28~01TF8DKFD49SRE6Q9PE0C2LAES00000J: Inside Interaction Block: ScreenForPriorities' label='' level='2' />**
15:36:32.448 [T:1401135292433] {ScxmlMetric:1} **METRIC <extension sid='~283~01TF8DKFD49SRE6Q9PE0C2LAES0000' name='screen' namespace='http://www.slab.com/modules/classification' />**
15:36:32.448 ==>Connector::EventHandler Port=0 Proto=0 CallBack=<97446>
===>event:   event_id=3, id=0 handle=66, datasize=24
15:36:32.448 {TSync:3} HandleThreadData: << 24 bytes <<
15:36:32.448 {ILink:3} **Message 'external_service_request' sent to 'I2P'
    attr_ref_id [int] = 8165875
    attr_envelope [list, size (unpacked)=369] = 
       'Version' [str] = "1.0"
       'AppType' [int] = 90**
15:36:32.460 {SManager:1} **[IX]: >> GET >> (FMID=000ADaHVQEJC00 / SESSID=~28~01TF8DKFD49SRE6Q9PE0C2LAES0)**
```

message1

```
METRIC <log sid='~28~01TF8DKFD49SREES00000J' expr='~28~01TF8DKFD49SRE6Q9PE0C2LAES00000J: Inside Interaction Block: ScreenForPriorities' label='' level='2' />
```

message2

```
METRIC <extension sid='~283~01TF8DKFD49SRE6Q9PE0C2LAES0000' name='screen' namespace='http://www.slab.com/modules/classification' />
```

message3

```
==>Connector::EventHandler  Port=0 Proto=0 CallBack=<97446>
===>event:   event_id=3, id=0 handle=66, datasize=24
```

message4

```
Message 'external_service_request' sent to 'I2P
    attr_ref_id [int] = 8165875
    attr_envelope [list, size (unpacked)=369] = 
       'Version' [str] = "1.0"
       'AppType' [int] = 90
```

message5

```
[IX]: >> GET >> (FMID=000ADaHVQEJC00 / SESSID=~28~01TF8DKFD49SRE6Q9PE0C2LAES0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this pattern:

```
/(?P<time>\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})\s?(?P<token>\[T\:\d+\])?\s?(?P<event_type>\{\w+\:\d+\})?\s?(?P<message>(.|\n)*?)(?=\n\d{2}:|$)/g
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xkHOhv/1

Comment: Thank you

I ran this over the entire file, I forgot that the message might also contain a time with the same format so this got stuck at a line like this in the message.


``
`Jan 2021 08:42:09.6640 (UTC)"`

Comment: I've updated regex pattern for your new case, please check

Answer (score 0):

In the example data there seem to be 6 messages that would match the pattern, including:

`15:36:32.448 {TSync:3} HandleThreadData: << 24 bytes <<`

You might use:

```
^(?P<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d{3})(?:\s+(?P<token>\[T:\d+]))?(?:\s+(?P<event_type>\{\w+:\d+}))?\s+(?P<message>.*(?:\n(?!\d{1,2}:).*)*)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?P<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\.\d{3})` Named group `time`, match a time like pattern
- `(?:\s+(?P<token>\[T:\d+]))?` Optional non capture group with named group `token`, match 1+ whitespace chars `[T` 1+ digits and `]`
- `(?:\s+(?P<event_type>\{\w+:\d+}))?` Optional non capture group with named group `event_type`, match 1+ whitespace chars `{` 1+ word chars `:`  1+ digits and the `}`
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?P<message>` Named group `message`

  - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

    - `\n` Match a newline
    - `(?!\d{1,2}:)` Negative lookahead, assert the the line does not start with 1-2 digits and `:`
    - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat to match all lines
- `)` Close group `message`

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/0zbMGq/1).

Comment: Thank you I ran this over the entire file, I forgot that the message might also contain a time with the same format so this got stuck at a line like this in the message. 

`Jan 2021 08:42:09.6640 (UTC)"`

Comment: @newmember can you give a regex101 example with the data where that breaks? The negative lookahead asserts only after a newline, so that should not be a problem with `Jan 2021 08:42:09.6640 (UTC)`

Comment: This is the complete line.

`    'Header_Date' [str] = "Sun, 22 Jan 2021 12:27:38 -0400 (AST)" `

Comment: @newmember So something like this? https://regex101.com/r/YeyNps/1 Else can you update the regex demo with the real data?

Answer (score 0):

I took another look, this works by lookahead for the first group time.
I aslo added a few of these `(\[T\:)?` `(\]\s{)?` `(\}\s)?`to leave just the value for the group

`(?P<time>^(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}.\d{3}))\s(\[T\:)?(?P<token>\d{15})?(\]\s{)?(?P<event_type>.*\:\d)?(\}\s)?(?P<message>[\s\S]*?)(?=(?1))`

Comment: I think that will not match the last line right? https://regex101.com/r/Spjo0w/1